# How to set custom font for xamarinf forms application

Tags: fonts, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

Iam trying to set custom font for entire xamarin forms app using style in app.xaml. But Im getting unhandled exception for the same.

```
<OnPlatform x:Key="AppFontFamily" x:TypeArguments="x:String"
      Android="customfont.otf#CustomFont-Regular">
</OnPlatform>

<Style x:Key="labelFont" TargetType="Label">
        <SetterProperty Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource AppFontFamily}"></SetterProperty>
      </Style>
```

Using style in my content page as follows

```
<Label Style="{StaticResource labelFont}"></Label>
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: Have you read the docs?  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts/#Using_a_Custom_Font

Comment: @Jason , Yes Im working with reference to the same, but how to add a common font for entire application, I mean from a font file

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a font for all labels using a font file you need to create a custom renderer. There, override OnElementChanged like this:

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        try
        {
            Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, path);
            Control.Typeface = font;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unable to make typeface:" + ex);
        }
    }
```

However, if you want to be able to set a custom font for every single label you need to create (in pcl) a custom label class inheriting from Label and add to it a font property (to be precise - property which you'll use to pass font file's path).

```
public static readonly BindableProperty CustomFontProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "CustomFont",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(CustomLabel),
            default(string));

    public string CustomFont
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CustomFontProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CustomFontProperty, value); }
    }
```

Then in your renderer you can read this property like this:

```
var label = Element as CustomLabel;
string path = label.CustomFont;
```

Be aware that path in Android uses '/' as separators, not '.' as in Forms.